# How to correctly link opencv library to clion?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need help with linking opencv library to my clion project. I am trying to do this on Windows 10. I've tried to do following steps:
- Install OpenCV from opencv.org in verssion 4.5.1
- Add C:\OpenCV_4.5.1\build\x64\vc15\bin to system PATH variable
- Add lines to CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(opencv)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(opencv main.cpp)

set(OpenCV_DIR "C:\\OpenCV_4.5.1\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

But the library still doesn't work. After compiling I'm getting these errors:

```
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
```

I don't know how to solve this, I will be verry greatful for helping me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x64\vc15` means those opencv binaries are compiled for Visual Studio 2019 64bits. Is your CLion using this compiler version/arch too?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I have mingw-w64 compiler installed for CLion. How can I generate the binaries for my CLion's compiler?

Comment: Assuming you don't have MSVC2019 installed and OpenCV doesn't provide precompiled mingw64 binaries, you'll have to compile OpenCV from source with mingw64.

Comment: I've done mingw configuration and it helped, so the problem is solved. Thank you very much for helping me.